# How to compile bash?

Tags: linux, bash

How to compile bash? I did small modifications to the code I got from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.2.tar.gz. I want to see those changes. Can anyone please point to me simple steps to compile bash?

Comment: On which system? If you are running any standard linux distro, there is probably a way to use the distribution's source package, change it and compile it.

Comment: I would like to keep it as a separate stand alone program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can first run

```
cd bash-4.2

./configure --prefix=/usr                     \
        --bindir=/bin                     \
        --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/bash-4.2 \
        --without-bash-malloc             \
        --with-installed-readline

make

make install
```

Also refer http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter06/bash.html for more information

Comment: The downloaded tar ball does not have configure script.

Comment: Run autoconf and automake

Comment: Also, configure.in file is not present. How can I use autoconf?

Comment: I have downloaded same package http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.2.tar.gz and able to find configure file

Comment: you just need to cd bash-4.2 and run autoconf there

Comment: oops! The download interrupted in the middle and hence I do not have complete set of files. Thanks

Comment: Installing directly to `/bin` is probably a bad idea until you know the modified version works.

Comment: @chepner:I agree with you,Its good idea to test modified bash by ./bash in bash-4.2 directory without make install

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to compile Bash is:

cd to the directory containing the source code and type `./configure` to configure Bash for your system. If you're using csh on an old version of System V, you might need to type `sh ./configure` instead to prevent csh from trying to execute configure itself.
Running configure takes some time. While running, it prints messages telling which features it is checking for.

like

```
/bash-4.2$ ./configure
```

Type `make` to compile Bash and build the bashbug bug reporting script.

```
 /bash-4.2$ make
```

Optionally, type `make tests` to run the Bash test suite.

```
/bash-4.2$ make tests
```

Type `make install` to install bash and bashbug. This will also install the manual pages and Info file.

```
/bash-4.2$ make install
```

The configure shell script attempts to guess correct values for various system-dependent variables used during compilation.

Comment: configure script is not present. As well I cannot run autoconf as the folder also doesn't have configure.in file