# Catalina bash shopt direxpand missing

Tags: bash, macos, shopt

I'm new to macOS coming from Windows and Linux. I want to use bash and found how to upgrade bash on Catalina, version now:

`GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0)`, also installed coreutils.

I'm trying to set direxpand in .bashrc (which works as expected in *nix variants):
`shopt -s direxpand`

But when .bashrc is sourced I get an error:

`-bash: shopt: direxpand: invalid shell option name`

Spent a couple of hours searching online and can't find an answer, can anyone help?

**Update 28/07/20 14:08 GMT**

Interesting, following other advice before posting, I installed bash with brew and had to set my shell to `/usr/local/bin/bash` for the terminal app to use it.

So output from `bash --version`:

`GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0)`

But `echo $BASH_VERSION` gives:

`3.2.57(1)-release`

So something not right there?

Also, output from running `shopt` does not show direxpand.

**Solved 28/07/20 20:00 GMT**

For anyone with a similar problem, here's what I found.

bash installed with Catalina did not include the same shell options I have in linux.

The full solution is to install coreutils and bash with brew:
`brew install coreutils bash`

Then add the new version of bash to shells:
`sudo vi /etc/shells` add `/usr/local/bin/bash`

Then change your user shell:
`chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash`

Then in terminal preference > general > shells open with > command (complete path) add the new bash `/usr/local/bin/bash`

After that `shopt -s` confirms that direxpand is now an option and my .bashrc works as expected.

Comment: Add output of `echo $BASH_VERSION` and `shopt -s direxpand` to your question (no comment).

Comment: 5.0.18 is the latest release, so it's normal that you can't find anything about it on the internet. File a bug report at bug-bash@gnu.org

Comment: I'm running Catalina 10.15.6 with GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0). `shopt -s` works fine. I installed via HomeBrew. I suspect you compiled from source, yourself.

Comment: Apologies to anyone reading in the last 10 minutes, I posted the output in the wrong order above, now corrected.

Comment: After installing bash with HomeBrew and changing your default login shell to point to `/usr/local/bin/bash`, did you logout and log back in again?

Comment: Yep, even rebooted since then :(

Comment: Just to check @JRFerguson, `shopt -s` works ok, it's just that `direxpand` is missing

Answer (score 0):

When running `shopt` without arguments you can see the available shopt options you can set. In your case I expect `direxpand` it's not there.

The workings of the `direxpand` shopt option depends on the readline library. If bash is compiled without readline support this option will not be there. I expect that is the case for you.

An option would be to compile bash yourself. The accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644870/how-to-compile-bash) will show you how to compile bash yourself. You can add the `--enable-readline` option in configure to force turn on readline support.

Note: compiling yourself might require you to get the readline library in your OS. I expect bash was compiled without it because it is not easily available, but that is for you to figure out.

Comment: Thanks @Veda, I want to avoid compiling at this stage if possible, with the extra info I added above I'm sure it's a config issue.